# where is my jquery ui css file?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i have following load of js files in my scripts folder, this from Nuget and files in Contents folder but i cannot find jquery-ui.css file so i dont have themes for my jquery controls

scripts folder

[image]

Contents folder

[image]

how do i get that jquery-ui.css file?

Comment: Do `Ctrl + ; ` in visual studio and find it.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi not found!

Comment: Please check your project folder and "package" folder.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi if not found there should be a way to DL it

Comment: `packages\jQuery.UI.Combined.1.8.24\Content\Content\themes\base` this is the path something like

Comment: Sry actual path is `Content\themes\base` in your folder.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi i cannot find jquery-ui.css in it! but have all the other controls related css files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98101/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-phill-greggan).

Answer (score 0):

Here in Visual studio `Ctrl + ;` to search any file in solution explorer.

For **Asp.net MVC** project

Here you can find all **CSS**

path `projectName\Content\themes\base`

and **scripts** in

path `projectName\Scripts`